# Getting objects out from Firebase(Json)

Tags: android, json, firebase

I am new to firebase and Json so having some basic troubles with it. My Json file in Firebase is built like this:

```
{
  "workout" : {
    "Heavy Chest and Arms" : [ "Bench press", "Incline Dumbbell Press", "Cable Crossover", "Bicep Barbell Curls", "Alternate Dumbbell Curls", "Preachers Curls", "V-Bar Triceps Extensions", "Skull Crushers", "Sitting Calf raises" ],
    "Light Back and Shoulders" : [ "Pull Ups", "Chins", "Cable Rows", "Lateral Pulldowns", "Dumbbell Rows", "Reverse Flies", "Arnold Press", "Side Raises", "Front Raises", "Rotary Cuffs" ]
  }
}
```

First I want to get out a list with all the workouts, that list would contain Heavy Chest and Arms","Light Back and shoulders". After that I want to get out all the elements(child?) in those list, example "Bench press","Incline Dumbell press" etc. I tried several times for hours now experimenting with this:

```
myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                List<String> messages = dataSnapshot.getValue();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think that JSON structure is going to cause you grief. It's generally a good idea to paste the actual data structure into your question so we have a clear picture. You can do that by going to your Firebase dashboard and select the Export Data option at the top right - then open the downloaded file and copy/paste into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better structure to get you going

```
workouts
  workout_id_0
     category: "Heavy Chest and Arms"
     elements
        element_id_0: true
        element_id_1: true
  workout_id_1
     category: "Light Back and Shoulders"
     elements
        element_id_0: true

elements
  element_id_0
    name: "Bench press"
    description: "While laying flat on your back, arms at 90 degrees etc"
  element_id_1
    name: "Incline Dumbbell Press"
    description: "Incline the backboard 30 degrees and etc etc"
```

You can do some snappy things with this structure:

Say you want to include a bench press in both the Heavy Chest and Light back workouts. This structure enables you to re-use your elements.

A year from now, you want to change the name of Bench press to Bench Press SUPER DUPER. You just change the name: within the element_id_0 and that falls into place

You can easily query for which workouts include element_id_1, the Incline dumbbell press

You can easily change the name of your workout. Instead of Light Back and Shoulders, it could be Light Lower Back and Shoulders with just changing one child node.

You should further consider how you want to use your data; do you need to find all elements that are just for the legs and create a workout based on those? Do you need to query or add additional data?

To print out all of the workout category names:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var workout = snapshot.val();
  console.log("Category: " + workout.category);
  //the element references are here too! elements = workout.elements
});
```

It will take a little code to get the element names for each workout but this should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a NoSQL database and as such should not be treated like a normalized SQL database.

To oversimplify you store data in the way you want to retrieve your data, even if that means saving the same data in separate places.

If you want to retrieve a list of workouts, have a workout names object that contains just the workout names (e.g. Heavy chest and arms, Light back and shoulders). Then if you want to retrieve the child elements, do so from another object that matches what you provided in the question.

Some [good reading](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html) to cement this idea.