# List get empty when getting data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Trying to retrieve data from a child called category in my Firebase and save that in a List called testList. The thing is that the list end up empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "elements" : {
    "element_id_0" : {
      "description" : "While laying flat on your back, arms at 90 degrees etc",
      "name" : "Bench press"
    },
    "element_id_1" : {
      "description" : "Incline the backboard 30 degrees and etc etc",
      "name" : "Incline Dumbbell Press"
    }
  },
  "workouts" : {
    "workout_id_0" : {
      "category" : "Heavy Chest and Arms",
      "elements" : {
        "element_id_0" : "true",
        "element_id_1" : "true"
      }
    },
    "workout_id_1" : {
      "category" : "Light Back and Shoulders",
      "elements" : {
        "element_id_0" : "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some of my applicaton code that I use.

```
 myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/workouts");
    myFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                testList.add(child.child("category").getValue().toString());

            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I also tried with this instead of the above and this didn´t work either...

```
 Firebase myFirebaseRef;
    List<String> testList;
    long räknare;
     private static final String TAG = "Anders";

    // ArrayAdapter<Integer> timeAdapter;
   // ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> timeAdapter;
    List<String> messages;

    Integer[] sets= {1,2,3,4,5};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseio.com/workouts");

        myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Log.d("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " workouts");
                for (DataSnapshot workoutSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Workout workout = workoutSnapshot.getValue(Workout.class);
                    testList.add(workout.getcategory());
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I created a Workout class for that:

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * Created by Anders on 2016-02-28.
 */
public class Workout {


   // private String workouts;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String category;
    private String elements;


    private Workout() {}
        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts

  /*  Workout(String category,String elements){
        this.category=category;
        this.elements=elements;
    }
*/
//    public String getWorkout() {
//
//        return workouts;
//    }
    public String getcategory() {
        return category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add one more child

```
myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/workouts");
myFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {


            testList.add(child.child.child("category").getValue().toString());  <------- Here

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Why would this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do exactly what you are asking:

If you want to retrieve one category and you know the path, that's easy

```
ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/workouts/workout_id_1/category");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent etc etc
```

That will return the value at that (and only that) path, which is "Light Back and Shoulders"

If you want to get all of the categories, you need to read in all of the workout nodes, and then extract the category from the snapshots.

Also, please note the answer to your previous question also contains an answer to this question:

[Getting objects out from Firebase(Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688990/getting-objects-out-from-firebasejson/35690020#35690020)

Comment: Yes tried using that code but didn´t really understand how to use it in my case. But I am very thankful for your suggestions :)

Comment: Check out the Firebase website guide for [Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html). The answers you seek are in the Read Event Types section.

Comment: Here's where to start. Create a new project. Go to the Retrieving Data section on the website, copy and paste the code from the very first example on the page into your project, then change the ref from what's there to your ref "https://myfirebaseio.com/workouts" and run the code, it will read in all of your workouts, and print them out. If that doesn't work, then something else is the issue; misconfigured app or maybe rules are wrong if you set any up.

Comment: Did that but now i get the following error: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
                                                                             at [Source: java.io.StringReader@34583a9e; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: org.example.anders.eazy.Workout["elements"])